# How can I access my web server remotely

Tags: networking, server, internet, remote

I have set up my web server and can access through all my computers in the my network now I want to make it public. I forwarded port 80 to the web server (192.168.2.9) but when I use my public IP to access the server it doesn't work! I use xubuntu with apache2 and phpmyadmin.

Also I want that phpmyadmin is not visible in the network but only at the localhost!

Comment: When you say `I forwarded port 80 to the web server`, you mean you configured the router for this?

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is for home? You'll need to check your router to make sure that port forwarding is properly configured. Also, your ISP may block incoming port 80 because many of them do not allow hosting a web server unless you have a business account. If that is the case then you might need to use a different external port and forward it to port 80 of your web server.

And what do you mean by "it doesn't work"? What do you see? What is the error?

Comment: If I go to http://publicip/ nothing happend but when I go to http://192.168.2.9/ I can get on the page, that is what i mean with it doesn't work (excuse me for my english). So lets say I want to test if my ISP is blocking port 80, I can use port 8080 aswell right? How do I configure that because Apache is listening on port 80. (I have a DDNS account aswell)

Comment: You have to configure your router to forward WAN requests on 8080 to 80 on your LAN to your webserver. You'll have to check your routers manual for how to do that since each router is different.

Comment: Just open port 8080 to the web server right and after that I don't have to configure something in xubuntu?

Comment: @Teezy well you'll have to configure Apache to listen on port 8080 if it's not already

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Nevermind solved

Comment: Don't forget to add any information required and mark the question as solved.